# reducing line height on cufon text

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, cufon

Having a problem reducing the line height on a Cufon heading. Using the line-height property but doesn't seem to do anything, p.s I've checked for any conflicting CSS rules, any wise words? :)

This is it
http://www.warface.co.uk/clients/detail-shoppe

Its the header under the 'New' Bubble I would like to tighten up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can't use line-height on Cufon unless your page DocType is set to Strict. Transitional doctypes won't work - if you're willing to change your doctype to Strict, you can play with the line-height on cufon. Bear in mind, though, that changing the doctype on a completed page may screw up your design a bit - you might have to backtrack a little to straighten things out.

Comment: I changed it to Strict and still seems to be acting the same

Comment: Hard to know what you're doing without looking over your shoulder, but read the Known Bugs for cufon: http://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/known-bugs-and-issues - you'll see that line-height is listed there as not working under non-strict. I've had the same issue before, and fixed it with a change in Doctype declaration, so if you want to be able to make line-height changes, change the doctype first and debug any other issues after. That's my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

This is it
http://www.warface.co.uk/clients/detail-shoppe

Its the header under the 'New' Bubble I would like to tighten up